# mensaje de error del servidor Post size exceeded allowed limits

Tags: javascript, c#, visual-studio, azure

estoy verificando un proceso en visual 2010

tengo un checkbox dinamico el cual tiene mas de 13mil registros, estoy marcando todos los registro
para luego desmarcar solo 29.

al momento de dar en conciliar
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
me da el siguiente mensaje por consola
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

puse un punto de interrupción en el cs pero no entra. se queda cargando la pagina y no continua.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

según lo que he investigado es una configuración del azure. pero no se con certeza que es.

pero cuando hago el mismo proceso con menos datos en el checkbox no me da ningun error.

también tengo este codigo de js que hace los recorridos         function chequearTodos(control, atributo) {
function chequearTodos(control, atributo) {
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

```
            for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
                if (inputs[i].type == "checkbox" && inputs[i].id.indexOf(atributo) != -1) {
                    inputs[i].checked = control.checked;

                    if (atributo == 'cbExtracto') {
                        sumarSeleccionados(inputs[i], 'Extracto');
                    } else {
                        sumarSeleccionados(inputs[i], 'Sistema');
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: parece que estas recibiendo mucha informacion al mismo tiempo y la configuracion/servidor no tiene los recursos necesarios/asignados para manejarlo

Comment: tienes que hacer una re-evaluacion de la arquitectura del software ... ya que estas entrando en temas de volumen de datos que en la practica puede no ser correcto ...

Comment: en mi caso lo del checkbox es correcto pero si estas enviado los vacios y los llenados, recibir 13K de campos en el servidor es excesivo...

Comment: solo estoy mandando los checkbox marcados. hay alguna recomendacion que me puedan dar para manejar este inconveniente?

Comment: no brindamos recomendaciones en el sitio.

Comment: como te desia ... no es una solucion pero puedes verificar cuanto es la cantidad de variables por POST que acepta tu servidor y ver si puedes incrementarlo

Comment: la función que indico no es la causante?, no hay manera de quizás cambiar el codigo. la unica opcion seria validar en el servidor. disculpen las preguntas. pero para estar mas seguro del como le puedo responder al PO que tiene acceso al servidor

Comment: no, la funcion que indicas no es la causante... en realidad la causante es esta: _Post size exceeded allowed limits_

Comment: eso es un problema de arquitectura

Comment: efectivamente, realice el proceso de envió desde postman y recibo la misma respuesta. error de conexión. gracias.

Comment: entonces si es por el numero de variables que envias??? lo solucionaste??? eso tiene que ver con temas de configuracion: aumentar la capacidad de variables que puedes recibir en el servidor; arquitectura: controlar como se envian los datos y presentar mejores interfaces de usuarios.

Comment: si, tiene que ver con temas de configuracion del lado del backend. y para el lado del front se pueden dividir el numero de peticiones, en mi caso se pueden dividir los 13mil registros en varios llamados post.

Comment: pero meter varios post como que no es lo mas optimo...

Comment: fue una de las opciones que se tuvieron en cuenta. sin embargo. como son conciliaciones bancarias. se indico al cliente que divida el valor de 2000mil millones en cantidades mas pequeñas para que pueda conciliar menos registros

Comment: bueno ten en cuenta que eso es un parche y no una solución eficiente... al final esto puede dar problemas de escalabildiad y/o errores por el tiempo que demora la ejecución...

Comment: gracias. lo tendre en cuenta.